# How to encrypt the Cordova plugin source code

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, encryption, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-proguard

I'm working on ionic mobile app with angularjs ,and to encrypt the source code of the ionic app , we have used the Cordova plugin "crypt file" to encrypt the code at build time.
After doing APK reverse engineering we found that the root folder "assets/www" is encrypted as expected, but by using the "java decompiler" tool we can access the plugins source code which is "java code" & get the decryption key.

So, is there any way to encrypt or hide the plugins folder so that the attacker couldn't see what plugins we have used in the app through the APK?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ProGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard) to obfuscate the Java source code.

[cordova-plugin-proguard](https://github.com/greybax/cordova-plugin-proguard) makes it easy to integrate into a Cordova project.

Comment: I have add the above plugin, but still when I opened the .jar file from the generated apk I can see the java code of the used plugins !

Comment: The default ProGuard rules of that plugin [exclude Cordova plugin classes](https://github.com/greybax/cordova-plugin-proguard/blob/master/proguard-custom.txt#L55) from obfuscation because they are entry points - i.e. if they are obfuscated then the JS layer will call to a class/method that no longer exists. Therefore you should configure [proguard-custom.txt](https://github.com/greybax/cordova-plugin-proguard/blob/master/proguard-custom.txt) to specifically target the sensitive classes you wish to obfuscate.